# Good book to study entanglement in detail

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

Can anybody suggest a good book to know about quantum entanglement? I am a master's student and I have good knowledge of quantum mechanics. I want to know more on this subject. It would also be useful if you can suggest some more sources to study entanglement in the scope of QFT too.

Comment: Try Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Isaac Chuang and Michael Nielsen https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Informat/aai-P4V9GJ8C?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: For entanglement in QFT these notes by Witten might be helpful. https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993

Comment: Quantum information meets quantum matter(by Bei Zeng et al): in this book many-body entanglement is discussed.